# java application Launcher not exist

Tags: eclipse, java

Hi I recently installed eclipse on my windows. I chose the installer that is customized for C/C++ but it has the java perspective also. after installing this version of eclipse, I also installed JDK.
everything (windows 7, eclipse , JDK and JRE) are 64 bits.

Now when i try to run a java project, I can not find 'Java Application' in the 'Run Configurations'

Appreciate your Comments and solutions.

I am including a screenshot of my eclipse :

[image]

Comment: But I see 'Java Application' in your screenshot.

Comment: @AlvinWong yes. Not that I didn't notice it, Since It doesn't have any icon on its side, I figured it might be a sort of sub group related to C/C++ customization( I know you didn't understand what I just said, me neither :) ) .anyway, when i press that item, it give an error as:"No tab group defined for launch configuration type org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication" . Considering I do have a java perspective, do I still need to check existence of jdt in my eclipse?(and how do I do that?)  or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You can also open the `main` class you want to launch, right-click anywhere in the file and choose *Run as > Java Application*

Comment: I did that but couldn't find 'Java Application'.the only option I have when I select 'Run' is : 'Run Configuration'

Answer (score 0):

I am answering to my question so that No body waste his time doing things I did.
When Eclipse has customized a package for C/C++, i shouldn't have expected every theory to work. 
So, I just installed a java customized package and .....